# Creating a separate navigation based on a Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have a group of pages that will not appear in the main nav menu but need to be presented on a single page as a drop-down jump menu. I chose this method to 'keep it simple' for the intern since he will just have to create the gallery, add a page, insert the shortcode and a custom field. I am also using this method so that the drop-down list is dynamic and will accomodate added pages on the fly.

On the template page, I added this code:

```
<div id="right_side_nav">
<?php  
    $media_artists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Media_Room_Title' ORDER BY 'meta_value'");
    foreach( $media_artists as $arty ):         
        echo $arty->meta_value . " ( " . $arty->post_id . " )<br><br>";     
    endforeach; ?> 
</div> <!-- END right_side_nav -->
```

So far, so good. I get the list and as another page with the proper custom field is added, the list dynamically adds it.

My question ... how do I create the anchor tag using the post_id?

I looked in the Codex for paths to pages/posts based on post_id but everything seemed to be about redirecting pages after changing the default structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

```
<div id="right_side_nav">
<?php 
    $media_artists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Media_Room_Title' ORDER BY 'meta_value'");

    foreach( $media_artists as $arty ):
        echo "<a href='" . get_permalink($arty->post_id) . "'>";
        echo $arty->meta_value . " ( " . $arty->post_id . " )</a><br><br>";
    endforeach;
?>
</div> <!-- END right_side_nav -->
```